# How to capture last string in batch file output and to continue or to pause

Tags: windows, batch-file, error-handling, cmd

I am writing a batch file, in which i am calling other batch file using CALL command for compilation. It outputs several outputs. (Success!!!/Building Errors...). I want to capture this last string for comparison and continue for further if success and pause the code if errors are occurred.
Here is the code....

```
@echo **********Compling %cdir% *******************
call mh123456
```

output of this compiler batch file(mh123456) is several lines at last it ends with Success!/Building Errors....I want to capture this last line and use if & goto labels for pausing if errors are occurred or continue if success is displayed.

Can you help you out for resolving this...

```
In file included from SinPWM.c:36:                 
LVPPG_TEST.h:143:2: warning: no newline at end of file
SinPWM.c: In function `SinPWM':
SinPWM.c:49: parse error before `status_sin'

Deleting ..\Sav_path.bat
1 file deleted              4,096 bytes freed
Building errors ...
```

This mh123456 batch file calls internally number of batch files but displays above result with at the end Building errors.../Success!!!

Comment: Is it an executable that issues the `Building errors` or `Success` string, or a batch file that echoes them?

Comment: mh123456 is a batch file inwhich it calls so many batch files inside... Building errors/Success are the strings which echoes by these batch files...mh123456 batch file is the compiler batch

Comment: Then you most likely should change that particular batch file to pause or continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the building errors / success...i have used the existence of the *.err file type for the compilation failure/success...Now my problem got solved...

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo **********Compling %cdir% *******************
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('call mh123456') do set "lastLine=%%a"

echo The last line displayed by mh123456 is: "%lastLine%"
```